# Run Selection in MATLAB from Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, matlab, command-line-arguments

I am running an SSH into a linux computer. The MATLAB GUI can be very slow and unresponsive. Is there a way I can use MATLAB in command line mode so that I can highlight part of my code and run that section? In GUI, it is possible to do this in the Editor window by right clicking and choosing 'Run Selection' or by pressing F9. In command line mode, I only know how to run the entire script.

In a similar vein, can I run a section of the code (the 'Run and Advance' button in the GUI) using command line?

Also, is it possible to see the workspace (like the Workspace window in the GUI version) from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is a no-desktop mode in MATLAB, which you can access by running it with -nodesktop parameter, this should provide you with what you need. You can find more info on [official MATLAB pages](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/)

Answer (score 1):

As Niemand said you can start MATLAB with the flag `-nodesktop`.

You won't be able to select and run a potion of code with `-nodesktop`.  You could just put that chunk of code in a separate function or script and call that.

If you're doing a lot of work without the GUI I would recommend looking at http://matlab-emacs.sourceforge.net.  This is a MATLAB mode for Emacs that provides many of the same functionalities as the MATLAB desktop.

Lastly check out `who` and `whos` to see the workspace variables.